# Why is Minecraft so much smoother on my MacBook when I’m running Linux?

Tags: macbook-pro

I’ve got a mid-2015 MacBook Pro with 16GB of RAM and no dedicated GPU. I play vanilla Minecraft a lot and the game itself runs alright, but not great, even with nothing else open but Firefox. If I flip to Firefox, I can’t even type a sentence without there being TREMENDOUS lag—like waiting-for-all-the-characters-to-appear kind of lag. It’s awful.

On a whim I tried running MC on the same MacBook while booted into Linux and it was smooth as silk! I could flip into other apps and they were also totally smooth.

Where do I begin figuring out what the heck is going on?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to improve the multitasking experience on macOS – while Minecraft is running? Or do you want to know *why* macOS and Linux handle Minecraft so differently?

Comment: Multitasking is certainly the bigger consideration for me. Minecraft itself runs fine enough. As for learning why versus learning how to improve it, I guess I’m interested in both. I run Windows on this machine as well and it multitasks just fine with Minecraft running. I’m surprised that out of these three operating systems, I have the most trouble multitasking on macOS [with Minecraft running]. I can have 20 other applications open, some of them rather intense, without any issues as long as Minecraft isn’t on.